# Error when running database migrations with NestJS, TypeORM and Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, migration, nestjs, typeorm

Using NestJS, docker-compose and Postgres on Ubuntu 20.4

Trying my first database migration with this app:

`npx typeorm migration:create -n mushroomRefactor`

`npm run build`

`npx typeorm migration:run`

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3"

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mushrooms-psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
  
volumes:
  mushrooms-psql:
```

ormconfig.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'db',
  port: 5423,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'pass123',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
};
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

# install app dependencies 
# use wildcard * to install package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app source
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run build

# entry file to run the app
CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

But it is returning:

`Error during migration run: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) { errno: -3001, code: 'EAI_AGAIN', syscall: 'getaddrinfo', hostname: 'db' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  the port `5432` in your NestJS app, cause the `5423` is the port which exposed to host machine. The port that shared between container is still `5432`